# TLS/SSLv3 in webview android

Tags: android, security, ssl, webview, sslv3

Can someone tell me how I can go about forcing webview in android to use TLS or simply block SSLv3 in android ?

```
11-07 11:40:16.711 D/WebActivity( 6474): onPageStarted-url : example.com
11-07 11:40:16.946 W/chromium( 6474): external/chromium/net/http/http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc:865: [1107/114016:WARNING:http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc(865)] Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant: 
11-07 11:40:16.951 E/WebActivity( 6474): Origin: example.com Quota: 9223372036854775807 Usage: 12661932
11-07 11:40:17.131 E/chromium( 6474): external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:792: [1107/114017:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(792)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
11-07 11:40:17.411 I/GATE    ( 6474): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_ERROR</GATE-M>
11-07 11:40:17.416 V/webkit  ( 6474): reportError errorCode(-11) desc(Couldn't establish a secure connection.)
11-07 11:40:17.416 E/WebActivity( 6474): onReceivedError-description:Couldn't establish a secure connection. -Error Code: -1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find solution for the issue ?? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same. It is purely server side configuration issue. I just verified from this [link](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) that whether those TLS and SSL version are enabled or not because Android version below 4.4 uses TLS1.0,1.1